# gumby framework CSS framework

Tags: css, css-frameworks, gumby-framework

I need to develop a easy web site, I usually use bootstrap CSS framework, but this I want to use Gumbyn which allow me to 16 columns instead of 12.

I was wondering if :

- Can I change the green color easily?
- How can I use a fixed layout instead of a fluid one?
- is it compatible with all browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the green. Just add a second style sheet and make sure to include it after gumby, then add rules for your colors. And if you remove the @media rules from gumby it will be a fixed layout. I am sure it is compatible.

Comment: I need to change the tabs color, can you be a bit more precise?

Comment: Can you send me a link of any page around using gumby with the tabs you want to change on it.